# SELECT Tableview cell as per result from API

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How to pass previous selected cell by its string. From API i'm getting result by "|" separated, then i'm putting it back into `array` after removing the separator. But how to pass the result into the `tableView` which will have selected tableview cell as per result.

This is dummy code of how I'm doing the selection and saving the result into an array.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController
{
let limit = 5
var lastSelectedIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: -1, inSection: 0)
    var genreList = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"]
var stringRepresentation = String()
var result = [String]()
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel!.text = genreList[indexPath.row]

    if cell.selected
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    }
    return cell
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
    if let sr = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
        if sr.count == limit {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops", message:
                "You are limited to \(limit) selections", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: {action in
            }))
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return nil
        }

    }

    return indexPath
}
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    print("selected  \(genreList[indexPath.row])")

    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    if cell!.selected == true
    {
        cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
        result.append((cell?.textLabel?.text)!)
        print(result)
    }
    else
    {

        cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
        print(result)
    }
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let deselectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    result = result.filter { $0 != deselectedCell?.textLabel?.text }

    stringRepresentation = result.joinWithSeparator("|") // "1-2-3"

    print(stringRepresentation)

    deselectedCell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None

}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return genreList.count
}

}
```

Comment: Is your tableview have multiple selection mode?

Comment: Yes, Upto 5. Please check code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to select cell like this way, use your `result` array for that

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel!.text = genreList[indexPath.row]
    if result.contains(genreList[indexPath.row])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    }
    return cell
}
```

Now change `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` like this

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{   
     tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
     if (self.result.count != limit) {   
         if (self.result.contains(genreList[indexPath.row])) {
             let index = self.result.indexOf(genreList[indexPath.row])
             self.result.removeAtIndex(index)
         }
         else {
             self.result.append(genreList[indexPath.row])
         }
     }
     else {
         if (self.result.contains(genreList[indexPath.row])) {
             let index = self.result.indexOf(genreList[indexPath.row])
             self.result.removeAtIndex(index)   
         }
         else {
             let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops", message:
            "You are limited to \(limit) selections", preferredStyle: .Alert)
             alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: {action in
         }))
             self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
         }
     }
     stringRepresentation = result.joinWithSeparator("|")
     self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**Note:** Remove `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` method from `ViewController` now there is no need of that method.

Comment: In didSelectRowAtIndexPath - Can you please explain self.result.append(sender.tag) ? Its giving error.

Comment: Thanks. But one issue after selecting 5 cells (which is limit). Then when I deselect that previously selected cell then its showing Alert of 5. That cell is not getting deselect as it was already selected. I think deselect is needed.

Comment: Check my edit for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` this will solve your problem :)

Comment: Its not showing any alert but still CELL is not getting deselected.

Comment: Have your replace the whole code of didSelect with new one?

Comment: Yeah. Sorry, its not the issue with your code. I didn't passed the fetched data correctly. Thanks. You literally gave me the whole code and also explained it.

Comment: Welcome mate, Happy to help, Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

create one model class and get values or array from api then implement this code

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")

        let relModel = bussArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! BussinesModel

        cell?.textLabel?.text = relModel.businesses_name
        var imageView : UIImageView
        imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 15, 15))

        if relModel.check
        {
            imageView.image = UIImage(named:"checked_checkbox")
        } else{
            imageView.image = UIImage(named:"checkbox_unchecked")
        }
        cell!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
        cell!.tintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        cell!.accessoryView = imageView

        return cell!
    }
```